# .net, windows application called from hotkey like google desktop

Tags: .net, windows-7

This might be a simple question for some people since it was quite hard to google it

but... I would like to make my application ( the exe file ) be called from a whatever hot key I define... like google desktop do when Ctrl is pressed twice...

any directions ?

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a Global Keyboard Hook

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

That will allow you to intercept all keyboard (or mouse) activity system wide and react, for example by bringing your program to the foreground.

Your program will have to be running to process key presses (e.g. in the system tray).